# Which of the following describes the return type and parameters of the Scanner method nextLine?

Tags: java

The question is: Which of the following describes the return type and parameters of the Scanner method nextLine?

I am pretty sure there are no parameters for nextLine. What I'm not sure of is if the return type is a String or void. Which one is it?

Comment: There are no parameters, and it returns a String.

Comment: Well, Java is open source so you can just search for the javadoc

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--):

```java
public String nextLine()
```

The public method has no parameters and return a String.

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner.nextLine()` has no parameters, and returns a String.

Consider this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerEx {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(input);

    }
}
```

If I enter:

```
foobar
```

It will print

```
foobar
```

If it was void, then it would return nothing. Not only would there be no output, but there would be a compilation error.